# how to test for equivalence of several variables in C

Tags: c

Say I wanted to test not just one, but several variables for equivalence in an if statement:

```
if(x1==x2==y1==y2){
    printf("Input values shouldn't be equal!");
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. What other approach can do this?

Comment: Do you mean that 1, 1, 1, 1 is invalid but 1, 1, 1, 2 is valid, or do they all have to be different?

Comment: 1,1,1,1 is invalid, but 1,1,1,2 is valid. Only if all the variables are set to the same value is it invalid.

Answer (score 26):

```
if (x1 == x2 && x2 == y1 && y1 == y2) { ... }
```

The result of the expression `a == b` will be an integer value of either 0 or 1.  the `==` operator is left-associative, so the expression `a == b == c` will be evaluated as `(a == b) == c`; that is, the result of `a == b` (0 or 1) will be compared against the value of c.  So in the code below

```
if (a == b == c) { ... }
```

the expression will only evaluate to true if a == b and c == 1 or a != b and c == 0.

Answer (score 10):

```
if (x1 == x2 && x1 == y1 && x1 == y2)
{
  printf("Input values shouldn't be equal!");
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
if( x1 == x2 && x2 == y1 && y1 == y2 ) { ... }
```

Comment: +1: Easier to understand that the code is looking for all of them equal.

Answer (score 6):

if they are integers you can use bitwise operations:

```
if ((x1 & x2 & x3 & x4) == (x1 | x2 | x3 | x4))
  // all are equal
```

It will evaluate to true IFF they are all the same

Comment: really nice! I thought about something similar - but you where faster.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a different approach, using a helper variable ( `count_equals` ) so that it's easy to do (**and understand**) exactly what you want.

```
int count_equals = 0;
if (x1 == x2) count_equals++;
if (x1 == y1) count_equals++;
if (x1 == y2) count_equals++;
if (x2 == y1) count_equals++;
if (x2 == y2) count_equals++;
if (y1 == y2) count_equals++;

if (count_equals == 0) /* all values are different */;
else if (count_equals == 6) /* all values are equal */;
else /* some values are equal */;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions presented here where mostly correct and easy to understand.

But I would prefer the [solution provided by Sany Huttunen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947738/how-to-test-for-equivalence-of-several-variables-in-c/1947776#1947776):

quoted:

```
if (x1 == x2 && x1 == y1 && x1 == y2)
{
  printf("Input values shouldn't be equal!");
}
```

**Here is the reason why**:

Although it seems not to be possible in this concrete case it directed me immediately into thinking about refactoring, like in:

```
(a*b) + (a*c) + (a*d)
```

which could be simplified into

```
a*(b+c+d)
```

as mentioned it's not possible to simplify in this concrete case however, because

```
(a*b) + (a*c) + (a*d)
```

follows different mathematical rules then

```
(a+b) * (a+c) * (a+d)
```

This has something to do with commutative, associative and distributive rules if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work because (x1 == x2) evaluates to the number 1, if true, and 0 if false, by the way. (x1 == x2 == x3) ends up evaluating as ((x1 == x2) == x3).

You'd need to write your own function to do this, I think.

Comment: Would upvote for the correct explanation, but it doesn't require a separate function, can be done inline.

Comment: My comment about the function was for a general purpose solution, i.e. test N things for equality. Obviously you can write out the 3 variable case inline.

Answer (score 0):

The following C code should answer your question:

```
if(x1==x2 && x1 == y1 && x1 == y2 && 
            x2==y1 && x2 == y2 &&
             y1 == y2)
{ printf("Input values shouldn't be equal!"); }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: All what you need is 3 equality tests, your boolean expression can be simplified ;)

Comment: No need to check all six permutations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method using Boolean logic

```
bool all_equal(false)
all_equal = x1 == x2;
all_equal = all_equal && (x2 == x3);
all_equal = all_equal && (x3 == x4);
```

A good compiler can code this using conditional assembly instructions and not disrupt the instruction prefetch queue.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is the incorrect usage of the == operator.  You would need to use something like:

```
if ((x1 == x2) && (x1 == y1) && (x1 == y2)) {
   printf("Input values shouldn't be equal!"); 
}
```

Comment: The problem is not precedence, it's that `==` doesn't do the same thing in C as `=` does in Lisp. Making it work that way would require more than a change in precedence.